# word positions inside UITextView (RTL and LTR issues)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextview, uitextposition

i am having really strange behavior when i try to get the rectangle frame around a word that contains charcaters from hebrew and english combined.
the following code gives me a correct rectange frame if i use only english
but if i use hebrew letters that is right to left alignment this code is not working
and the rectangle only contains the english language letters ...

```
pos = GetPosition (BeginningOfDocument, startIndexOfWord);
pos2 = GetPosition (BeginningOfDocument, endIndexOfWord);
range = GetTextRange (pos, pos2);
rec = GetFirstRectForRange (range);
```

example - "Acbדדג" gives me the "Acb" rectangle and "גדגדAA" gives me "AA" rectangle

any other key as " " and "_" and other behaves same as english key.
so even "שש " return me " " rectangle.
and the really strange thing is that "ש ש"  return me a correct rectangle.
i already spent to much time on this so i hope someone has the answers.
thanks.

Comment: I don't use monotouch or c# but can you use obj-c? try [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font] to return a CGRect.

Comment: i need the x and y coordinates of the screen to